# Javascript - using a button to determine if online or not

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working on something which will detect if there is a connection to the internet. This works by pinging an image file to see if it exists. Whilst the code as a whole works, I want it to NOT postback if it's offline (because it's a page that will be hosted online - so if it posts back when offline then it'll reload the page and do a "page not found"), yet still display the "offline" message:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ifServerOnline()" Text="Button" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ifServerOnline(ifOnline, ifOffline)
            {
                var img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
                img.onload = function ()
                {
                    ifOnline && ifOnline.constructor == Function && ifOnline();
                };
                img.onerror = function ()
                {
                    ifOffline && ifOffline.constructor == Function && ifOffline();
                };
                img.src = "http://www.mypage.com/pixel.jpg?" + Date.now;
            }

            ifServerOnline(function ()
            {
                alert("Online");
            },
            function ()
            {
                alert("Offline");
            });
        </script>
```

Obviously the mypage.com doesn't exist (unless it does, but it's not mine).

EDIT - final code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ifServerOnline(ifServerOnline1, ifServerOffline1);" Text="Button" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ifServerOnline(ifOnline, ifOffline)
            {
                var img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
                img.onload = function ()
                {
                    ifOnline && ifOnline.constructor == Function && ifOnline();
                };
                img.onerror = function ()
                {
                    ifOffline && ifOffline.constructor == Function && ifOffline();
                };
                img.src = "http://www.mypage.com/pixel.jpg?" + Date.now;
                return false;
            }

            function ifServerOnline1()
            {
                alert("Online");
                return false;
            }
            function ifServerOffline1()
            {
                alert("Offline");
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common approach is simply to return false at the end of the handler to prevent default control's behavior (which, in case of button, is to post the form):

```
function ifServerOnline(ifOnline, ifOffline)
{
    ...

    return false;
}
```

Also you may need this for client click handler (make sure to pass arguments to the `ifServerOnline` function:

```
OnClientClick="return ifServerOnline(ifServerOnline, ifServerOffline);"
```

Last thing. This method makes sure there is no postback after click at all. If you still want to make a postback in online case - you will probably have to do it manually in the `ifServerOnline` handler.

**Update.** Following up comments discussion - easiest way to define callback functions for you would be:

```
function ifServerOnline()
{
    alert("Online");
}

function ifServerOffline()
{
    alert("Offline");
}
```

Comment: Still posting back if I add it to the end of the ifServerOnline(ifOnline,ifOffline) ie - after the img.src url/

Comment: @user25730, have you edited the `OnClientClick` value as well? Also note that this might not work if you have other subscribers to this button's click

Comment: I'd try `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ifServerOnline()" Text="Button" />`.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin, that's basically the same thing,isn't it?

Comment: And with the OnClientClick="return ifServerOnline();" it's not returning any of the message boxes (though no postback)

Comment: Heh - yeah, I missed the last line too.

Comment: @user25730, oh, that's because you are actually calling `ifServerOnline` without arguments at all. DId not notice it initially, sorry. Will update the post

Comment: Seems to be going down the right track - just need to define ifServerOffline (I really need to actually learn some Javascript rather than cobble other people's code together).

Comment: @user25730, you do realize that you have it at the very bottom of the script tag, just without the name for some reason?

Comment: I thought I did, I just need to try and define it properly. As I said, I generally seem to suck at Javascript :)

Comment: @user25730, see the edit - probably the simpliest thing to do to get you going

Comment: Hooray - it works! And the definition - I just needed to change the ifServerOnline and ifServerOffline functions (which display the alerts) to ifServerOnline1 and ifServerOffline1 since ifServerOnline is already taken. Works perfectly thanks!